# Zoo visitor save member error

Tags: ee2, zoo-visitor

I'm using EE 2.7.3 and I have a fresh installation of zoo visitor (1.3.30). I migrated my members over to zoo (1 member) and tried to add a First Name and save. I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::update_username_password() in /var/www/mysite/system/expressionengine/third_party/zoo_visitor/ft.zoo_visitor.php on line 390
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by re-installing zoo visitor. 
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/12676#41054